Get the list of records to delete based on a column and list of tables
I have a table Employees:



EmployeeId
EmployeeMatricule




1
XCV


2
HKO



I have a list of EmployeeMatricule that I need to use to delete records from the table Employees and the tables which are in relationship with it having one of their columns name EmployeeId.
To find the tables with the EmployeeId column :
 SELECT table_name
        FROM all_tab_columns
        WHERE column_name = 'EmployeeId' AND table_name <> 'Employees'

I have as an output these tables as a result of the above query

EmployeeDepartment
SalaryPackage
SalaryPayroll

Let's say this is the list of EmployeeMatricule I have : XCV, HKO, MXP
So I want for each table EmployeeDepartment/SalaryPackage/SalaryPayroll :
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeDepartment
WHERE EmployeeId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId
    FROM Employees
    WHERE EmployeeMatricule IN ('XCV', 'HKO', 'MXP'))

The same query for SalaryPackage and SalaryPayroll.
I tried using a cursor :
DECLARE
    CURSOR table_cursor IS
        SELECT table_name
        FROM all_tab_columns
        WHERE column_name = 'EmployeeId' AND table_name <> 'Employees'; 

    v_table_name VARCHAR2(128);
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
    EmployeeId Employees.EmployeeId%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN table_cursor; 

    LOOP
        FETCH table_cursor INTO v_table_name; 

        EXIT WHEN table_cursor%NOTFOUND; 

        v_sql := 'SELECT EmployeeId FROM ' || v_table_name ||
                 ' WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId FROM employee WHERE EmployeeMatricule IN (''XCV'', ''HKO'', ''MXP''))';

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing SELECT on table: ' || v_table_name);

        FOR rec IN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql)
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EmployeeId: ' || rec.EmployeeId);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE table_cursor; 
END;

My current output is :

Executing SELECT on table : EmployeeDepartment


Executing SELECT on table : SalaryPackage


Executing SELECT on table : SalaryPayroll

While I am expecting to return the rows with EmployeeId to delete.

First you should escape a quote symbol in a string literal with double quote, e.g. select 'ab''cd''ef' from dual to return ab'cd'ef

Yes you are right it was a copy paste typo since I changed the real data with dummy one

IN ((..)) - don't you mean IN (..) ?

Yes, corrected that also

Don't SELECT and then DELETE. Just DELETE the values from the tables.
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (
    SELECT table_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  column_name =  'EMPLOYEEID'
    AND    table_name  <> 'EMPLOYEES'
    AND    owner       =  USER
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'DELETE FROM "' || t.table_name || q'[" t
      WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   employees e
        WHERE  e.employeeid = t.employeeid
        AND    e.EmployeeMatricule IN ('XCV', 'HKO', 'MXP')
      )]';
  END LOOP;
END;
/


If you need to print what was deleted then use a RETURNING ... INTO ... clause.
DECLARE
  v_ids SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (
    SELECT table_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  column_name =  'EMPLOYEEID'
    AND    table_name  <> 'EMPLOYEES'
    AND    owner       =  USER
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'DECLARE 
        v_ids SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
      BEGIN
        DELETE FROM "' || t.table_name || q'[" t
        WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   employees e
          WHERE  e.employeeid = t.employeeid
          AND    e.EmployeeMatricule IN ('XCV', 'HKO', 'MXP')
        ) RETURNING employeeid BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;
        :1 := v_ids;
      END;]'
      USING OUT v_ids;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t.table_name);
    FOR i in 1 .. v_ids.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ids(i));
    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE employees (employeeid, employeematricule) AS
SELECT 1, 'XCV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'HKO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'MXP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'XCV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AAA' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table1 (employeeid) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (employeeid) AS
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

Deletes the rows:
TABLE1
1
2
TABLE2
2

fiddle

Here's how.
Sample data first:
SQL> select table_name from user_tab_columns
  2  where column_name = 'EMPLOYEEID'
  3    and table_name <> 'EMPLOYEES';

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPLOYEEDEPARTMENT
SALARYPAYROLL

SQL> select * from employeedepartment
  2  where employeeid in (select employeeid from employees
  3                       where employeematricule in ('XCV', 'HKO', 'MXP'));

EMPLOYEEID DEPTID
---------- ------
         1 Dept 1
         2 Dept 2

SQL> select * From salarypayroll;

EMPLOYEEID PAYROLL
---------- ---------
         2 Payroll A

SQL>

In a procedure you do need dynamic SQL (because you don't know table name you'll actually use), but you don't execute immediate it for showing data; I'd suggest a refcursor instead. On the other hand, you do need it when deleting rows from those tables.
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3    l_empid employees.employeeid%type;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_t in (select table_name
  6                  from user_tab_columns
  7                  where column_name = 'EMPLOYEEID'
  8                    and table_name <> 'EMPLOYEES'
  9                 )
 10    loop
 11      open rc for 'select employeeid from ' || cur_t.table_name ||
 12                  ' where employeeid in (select employeeid from employees' ||
 13                  q'[                      where employeematricule in ('XCV', 'HKO', 'MXP'))]';
 14      loop
 15        fetch rc into l_empid;
 16        exit when rc%notfound;
 17        dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID = ' || l_empid);
 18
 19        execute immediate 'delete from ' || cur_t.table_name || ' where employeeid = ' || l_empid;
 20      end loop;
 21    end loop;
 22  end;
 23  /

It results in
Employee ID = 1
Employee ID = 2
Employee ID = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

What about data? Deleted in tables different from employees:
SQL> select * from employees;

EMPLOYEEID EMP
---------- ---
         1 XCV
         2 HKO

SQL> select * From employeedepartment;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from salarypayroll;

no rows selected

SQL>

